# How do I send an email attaching a file my app created using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Using Google Apps Script, how do I send an email attaching a file my app crafted at runtime? Here's the code I have so far... as you can see, it reads questions from a Form and responses, and drops both into a Google Docs template file that I copy, but I don't know what to add at the bottom in `attachments`:

```
function homeworkAssignments() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var allResponses = form.getResponses();  
  var index = allResponses.length - 1;
  var lastResponse = allResponses[index];
  var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses()
  var data = [];

  for (var i in itemResponses) {
    var answer = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    var question = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle();
    data.push([question, answer]);
  }

  var user = lastResponse.getRespondentEmail();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1vz2jbb3jeOiIWlHks53lkwsLIoYHJGpdVkJc9eVz0BE');
  var newFile = file.makeCopy('Homework assignments for ' +user);
  var id = newFile.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  for (var i in data) {
    var question = data[i][0];
    var answer = data[i][1];
    body.replaceText(question, answer);
  }

  var user = lastResponse.getRespondentEmail();

  MailApp.sendEmail(user, 'Homework Assignments', 'Reminder: complete the following homework assignments',
                { attachments: [


}
```

Comment: is your code complete? i see only an opening square bracket.

Comment: Improved the formatting of the Javascript (but some of it is missing down at the bottom).

Comment: Try something like:  `attachments: [newFile]`  Then post back what happened.

Comment: Improved the title and rephrased it at the top of the question section.

Comment: further improved the question